# Paypal DoDirectPayment showing invalid data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

Paypal

> `DoDirectPayment`: Invalid Data

I am using paypal's `DoDirectPayment` in my application which `ASP.NET MVC3` based using my sandbox developer's account.
I am passing this required string to paypal:

> VERSION=98.0&USER=deb-facilitator_api1.pppppppp.net&PWD=xxxxxxxxxxx&SIGNATURE=Axxxxx1bNozKCMMMMtXRD-aZoDAoA7NfvDKed45ouIN-.DZsdNksdh&METHOD=DoDirectPayment&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&IPADDRESS=122.163.32.32&AMT=40&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa&ACCT=4832592408827303&EXPDATE=072018&CVV2=947&FIRSTNAME=df&LASTNAME=dfgg&STREET=799+E+DRAGRAM+SUITE&CITY=TUCSON&STATE=AZ&ZIP=85705&COUNTRY=USA&CURRENCYCODE=USD

But I'm getting the error `10747` which states that it is due to some IP Address invalid format but as far I know I'm using the valid one. I'm getting this error on both `IIS 8.0` and development server of `Visual Studio 2010`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope this data is not real...

Comment: Thanks for concern data is changed and not real

Comment: IPAddress is optional. Could you remove `IPADDRESS=122.163.32.32` and try it again?